# How to create a csv from a document by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion, export-to-csv

I have a not standard XML file, that needs to convert to CSV, I've tried the xml.etree.ElementTree, but it doesn't work.

colunms can be the code, displayname, codedescription, isdisplayed,displayorder and codesetname.
the values are after equal sign.

is there a way to convert this file to CSV by using Python?

I've tried this way

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd

cols = ["code", "displayName", "codeDescription", "isDisplayed", "displayOrder","CodeSetName"]
rows = []

# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse1 = Xet.parse("./code.xml")
root = xmlparse1.getroot()


for i in root:
    
    code = i.find("Code").text
    displayName = i.find("displayName").text
    codeDescription = i.find("codeDescription").text
    isDisplayed=i.find("isDisplayed").text
    displayOrder=i.find("displayOrder").text
    CodeSetName=i.find("CodeSetName").text



rows.append({"code": code,"displayName": displayName,"codeDescription": codeDescription,"isDisplayed": isDisplayed,"displayOrder": displayOrder,"CodeSetName":CodeSetName})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('code.csv')
```

But it doesn't work. The srcipt shows can't get anything from .text
The format in the document is shown below.

```
<Codes>
    <Code code="value" displayName="value" codeDescription="value" isDisplayed="value" displayOrder="13423" CodeSetName="1234" />
    <Code code="value" displayName="value" codeDescription="value" isDisplayed="value" displayOrder="value" CodeSetName="value" />
</Codes>
```

Comment: Yes, in fact, there are many ways. Why don't you show us what you've tried? As it stands, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd

cols = ["code", "displayName", "codeDescription",
        "isDisplayed", "displayOrder", "CodeSetName"]
rows = []

# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse1 = Xet.parse("code.xml")
root = xmlparse1.getroot()

# Pandas
rows = []
for item in root:
    rows.append(dict(item.items()))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Output:

```py
code    displayName     codeDescription     isDisplayed     displayOrder    CodeSetName
value   value           value               value           13423           1234
value   value           value               value           value           value
```